# How to get the vertical and horizontal alignment by an integer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, alignment, bit-shift, bitmask

I'm trying to convert an integer value to a content alignment. The integer can hold both a horizontal and a vertical alignment at the same time.

First I created an enum, which describes all possibilities (i have to use the values of android Gravity class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html)

```
typedef enum{
    GravityHorizontalCenter         = 1,    // (0x00000001) 
    GravityLeft                     = 2,    // (0x00000002) 
    GravityRight                    = 5,    // (0x00000005) 
    GravityVerticalCenter           = 16,   // (0x00000010) 
    GravityTop                      = 48,   // (0x00000030) 
    GravityBottom                   = 80,   // (0x00000050) 
} GravityType;
```

So `int alignment = GravityRight | GravityTop` would be 53.

I want to check the alignment of my view-objects like this:

```
if ((textAlignment & GravityHorizontalCenter) == GravityHorizontalCenter){

    return NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}...
```

But there seems to be something missing, because for 53 the if statement `textAlignment & GravityHorizontalCenter) == GravityHorizontalCenter` returns `True`.

Comment: What are you attempting to do with your single `&`?

Comment: @Firo [AND bitwise operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't realize there was a syntax for this! I will be keeping this in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need masks for the the Vertical and Horizontal ranges.

```
typedef enum{
    GravityHorizontalCenter         = 1,    // (0x00000001) 
    GravityLeft                     = 2,    // (0x00000002) 
    GravityRight                    = 5,    // (0x00000005) 
    GravityHorizontalMask           = 7,    // (0x00000007) 
    GravityVerticalCenter           = 16,   // (0x00000010) 
    GravityTop                      = 48,   // (0x00000030) 
    GravityBottom                   = 80,   // (0x00000050) 
    GravityVerticalMask             = 112,  // (0x00000070) 
} GravityType;
```

Then you can do a test with:

```
(textAlignment & GravityHorizontalMask) == GravityHorizontalCenter
```

or

```
(textAlignment & GravityVerticalMask) == GravityTop
```

These values are only really suitable for direct comparison, since 5 (101 binary) and 1 (001 binary) overlap as bit masks. But since you are storing two values in the same number (the first 4 bits for the horizontal alignment, and the second 4 bits for the vertical alignment), you need a mask to isolate the range of bits that you want to compare.

Also, you should be aware that on Android the value of `LEFT` (the left gravity constant) is 3 and not 2. So if your enum really needs to be compatible with Android then your `GravityLeft` value is probably incorrect.

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth explaining the *why.*

Comment: @Chrizzor I'm not sure what you are asking. I showed you exactly how to test the values in my answer. You AND the alignment with either the horizontal or vertical mask, and then compare that result with the value you are trying to match.

Comment: @James Sorry, forget about my last comment. Thanks you so much for your help, now everything is working great!

Answer (score 1):

Because these values are not suited for being used as bit flags (masks).

`&` is not magic - it's just the bitwise `AND` operator. And if you bitwise `AND` a number with `1` then you compare the result to `1`, that only checks if the least significant bit was set in the original number, i. e. if it was odd. Thus, `(textAlignment & GravityHorizontalCenter) == GravityHorizontalCenter` will yield true for any odd number.

If you want to use numbers as flags, you have to make them different powers of two, like this:

```
GravityHorizontalCenter         = 1,
GravityLeft                     = 2,
GravityRight                    = 4,
GravityVerticalCenter           = 8,
GravityTop                      = 16,
GravityBottom                   = 32,
```

Comment: What you are saying may be true, but it's not particularly useful to the OP, since he needs to use the numbers he has for compatibility with Android.

Comment: @JamesHolderness But... there's **no way** to do bitmasking with inappropriate values (which these are), I'm not acting out the smart ass. If he needs to use these values, then some other approach shall be taken (direct comparison? An array? etc.).

Comment: I showed how to do this in my answer. It's almost exactly what he was doing except he was just ANDing with the wrong value. It's not bitmasking at an individual bit level, but masking out a range of bits for comparison.